Issue with OpenAPI Generated Python Client Handling 204 No Content Responses
I'm encountering an issue with a Python client generated from an OpenAPI specification using the openapitools/openapi-generator-cli tool. The problem arises when making a GET request to an endpoint that may return a 204 No Content status.
I have a Swagger/OpenAPI YAML specification with the following endpoint definition:
    '/api/v1/Sensor/now/{instanceUri}':
  get:
    tags:
      - Sensor
    parameters:
      - name: instanceUri
        in: path
        required: true
        schema:
          type: string
      - name: x-api-version
        in: header
        schema:
          type: string
    responses:
      '200':
        description: Success
        content:
          text/plain:
            schema:
              $ref: '#/components/schemas/Gkkg.Bff.Api.Contracts.TagValueResponses'
          application/json:
            schema:
              $ref: '#/components/schemas/Gkkg.Bff.Api.Contracts.TagValueResponses'
          text/json:
            schema:
              $ref: '#/components/schemas/Gkkg.Bff.Api.Contracts.TagValueResponses'
      '204':
        description: No Content
      '401':
        description: Unauthorized
      '403':
        description: Forbidden
    security:
      - Bearer:
          - sensor_read

It seems like the OpenAPI generator has produced code that recognizes the 204 response code, but still expects a return type of GkkgBffApiContractsTagValueResponses, which i think leads to an error when the response is empty and should return a 204.
Generated Function Example:
api_v1_sensor_now_instance_uri_get

GkkgBffApiContractsTagValueResponses api_v1_sensor_now_instance_uri_get(instance_uri)

Example

Bearer (JWT) Authentication (Bearer):

import time
import gkkg_api_python_proxy
from gkkg_api_python_proxy.api import sensor_api
from gkkg_api_python_proxy.model.gkkg_bff_api_contracts_tag_value_responses import GkkgBffApiContractsTagValueResponses
from pprint import pprint

configuration = gkkg_api_python_proxy.Configuration(
    host = "http://localhost"
)

# Configure Bearer authorization (JWT): Bearer
configuration = gkkg_api_python_proxy.Configuration(
    access_token = 'YOUR_BEARER_TOKEN'
)

with gkkg_api_python_proxy.ApiClient(configuration) as api_client:
    api_instance = sensor_api.SensorApi(api_client)
    instance_uri = "instanceUri_example"  # str | 
    x_api_version = "x-api-version_example"  # str |  (optional)

    try:
        api_response = api_instance.api_v1_sensor_now_instance_uri_get(instance_uri)
        pprint(api_response)
    except gkkg_api_python_proxy.ApiException as e:
        print("Exception when calling SensorApi->api_v1_sensor_now_instance_uri_get: %s\n" % e)

    try:
        api_response = api_instance.api_v1_sensor_now_instance_uri_get(instance_uri, x_api_version=x_api_version)
        pprint(api_response)
    except gkkg_api_python_proxy.ApiException as e:
        print("Exception when calling SensorApi->api_v1_sensor_now_instance_uri_get: %s\n" % e)

Parameters
Name Type Description Notes
instance_uri str
x_api_version str [optional]
Return type
GkkgBffApiContractsTagValueResponses
Authorization
Bearer
HTTP request headers
Content-Type: Not defined
Accept: text/plain, application/json, text/json
HTTP response details
Status code Description Response headers
200 Success -
204 No Content -
401 Unauthorized -
403 Forbidden -
When I use the generated Python client to call this endpoint, I encounter an ApiTypeError when the response status is 204 No Content:
ApiTypeError: Invalid type for variable 'received_data'. Required value type is GkkgBffApiContractsTagValueResponses and passed type was str at ['received_data']

If I make a direct HTTP requests with requests instead of using the generated client works without issues, and I get the 204 as expected.
Questions:
Why does the generated Python client fail with an ApiTypeError when handling a 204 No Content response, but works fine in Swagger UI?
How can I adjust the OpenAPI specification to handle 204 responses correctly in the Python client?
I dont want to touch the generated code.
Thanks

The issue you are facing is not that the API is failing. The problem is that when you get a 204 response it does not have any content. You are then trying to assign an empty content to your model GkkgBffApiContractsTagValueResponses.
You have to check where in your code you map the response to your model and handle that scenario appropriately.

Yes, but I’m quite surprised that the OpenAPI Generator doesn’t handle this when generating the code. It recognizes that a 204 response is possible, yet it still requires a GkkgBffApiContractsTagValueResponses to be returned.
